# Unable to use OrcFile.createReader to read from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, orc

I am having trouble reading an ORC file from S3 with the OrcFile.createReader option. I am using hive-exec-2.2.0.jar at the moment and am wondering if this is supported at all? Am i missing any configuration settings? See code below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
String accessKey = "***";
String secretKey = "***";

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", accessKey);
configuration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", secretKey);
configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "s3://<bucket>");

//configuration.set("fs.default.name", "s3://<bucket>");
//configuration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);

Reader reader = OrcFile.createReader(new Path("/some/path/file.orc"), OrcFile.readerOptions(configuration).filesystem(fs));
```

Exception - java.io.IOException: No such file.

The ReaderImpl seems to require either the fileMetadata or the OrcTail (both of which are null). Anything that i might be missing?

Update: So i managed to get out of the file not found exception by creating the s3 object with additional info (also fix the key) with 
--metadata="fs=Hadoop,fs-type=block,fs-version=1".  See --metadata.

It seems wrong/weird that the type of the orc file on s3 has to have those values for it to successfully retrieve the metadata.

Of course after this it barfs at getting the data, probably because the file formats differ(?).

in INode of package org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3;

```
public static INode deserialize(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        if (in == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(in);
            INode.FileType fileType = FILE_TYPES[dataIn.readByte()];
```

The dataIn.readByte is returning a larger value (FILE_TYPES is an array of size 2).

Comment: Is there any more to the exception?  It would seem that it should point to the line.  My guess is that it's the `file.orc` file that's missing but we'd need a bit more.

Comment: So i managed to get over the file not found exception by altering the s3 object key for the orc file i am attempting to read and also including --metadata ```--metadata="fs=Hadoop,fs-type=block,fs-version=1"``` <br/><br/>So now it barfs when it attempts to read the file around <br/><br/>```public static INode deserialize(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        if (in == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(in);
            INode.FileType fileType = FILE_TYPES[dataIn.readByte()];```
<br/><br/> in INode.class